# How to force A/V sync using mkvmerge and external time-codes?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, mkv

### Background

I'm working on a project where video and audio are algorithmic interpretations of an MKV source file where I use ffmpeg -ss and -t to extract a particular region of audio and video to separate files. I use scene changes in the video in the audio process (i.e. the audio changes on video scene change), so sync is crucial.

Audio is 48khz, using 512 sample blocks.
Video is 23.976fps (I also tried 24).

I store the frame onset of sceneChanges in a file in terms of cumulative blocks:

```
blocksPerFrame = (48000 / 512) / 23.976
sceneOnsetBlock = sceneOnsetFrame*blocksPerFrame
```

I use these blocks in my audio code to treat the samples associated with each scene as a group.

When I combine the audio and video back together (currently using ffmpeg to generate mp4(v) mp3(a) in an MKV container), the audio and video start off in sync but increasingly drifts until it ends up being ~35 seconds off. The worst part is that the audio lag is nonlinear! By non-linear, I mean that if I plot the lag against the location of that lag in time, I don't get a line, but what you see in the image below). I can't just shift or scale the audio to fit the video because of this nonlinearity. I cannot figure out the cause of this nonlinearly increasing audio delay; I've double and triple checked my math.

[image: Cumulative lag against time]

Since I know the exact timing of scene changes, I should be able to generate "external timecodes" (from the blocks above) for mkvmerge to perfectly sync the output!

### Subquestions:

1. Is this the best approach (beyond trying to figure out what went wrong in the first place)? As I'm using my video frames as a
   reference, if I use the scene changes as timecodes for the audio,
   will it force the video to match the audio or vice versa? I'm much less concerned with the duration than the sync. The video was much more laborious to produce, so I'd rather loose some sound than some frames.
2. I'm not clear on what numbers to use in the timecodes file.
   According to mkvmerge [documentation](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.external_timecode_files) "For video this is exactly
   one frame, for audio this is one packet of the specific audio type."
   **Since I'm using MP3, what is the packet size?** Ideally, I could specify a packetsize (in the audio-encoder?) that matches my block size (512) to keep things consistent and simple. Can I do this with ffmpeg?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the rates (frame-rate, bit-rate) constant or variable? Not that it would make the actual sync non-linear, but maybe it could throw off the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the cause of the issue in my code, so I never needed to follow through on my thought above. In discussion with the author of mkvmerge I did determine the following answers:

1. It would be best to fit the sync the video to the audio as some players use the audio timestamps (timecodes) as reference, and video is easier to slow down and speed up by players than audio.
2. There is no single packet size for audio. Packet size depends on the encoder and may even be different sizes at different parts of the stream. One would have to extract the number of samples in each packet from the MKV header, and use that to calculate the duration of each packet to generate timestamps.